# Finding conditional expectation for 3 tosses of a coin.

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

> We toss a symmetric coin three times. Let $X$ denote the number of tails in the first two tosses, and $Y$ the number of tails in the last two tosses.
>
> Find the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y = l$ for $l = 0, 1, 2$.
>
> Compute $E[X| Y = l]$ for $l = 0, 1, 2$.

**My Solution:**

Range of $X$ = $R_X = \{0,1 ,2\} = R_Y$ = Range of $Y$.

We know that in case of three coin tosses,

$\text{TTT} = (2,2)$
   $\text{TTH} = (2,1)$
   $\text{THT} = (1,1)$
   $\text{THH} = (1,0)$
   $\text{HTT} = (1,2)$
   $\text{HTH} = (1,1)$
   $\text{HHT} = (0,1)$
   $\text{HHH} = (0,0)$

So,

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Pattern} & \text{Count} \\\hline
(2,2) & 1\\\hline
(2,1) & 1\\\hline
(1,1) & 2\\\hline
(1,0) & 1\\\hline
(1,2) & 1\\\hline
(0,1) & 1\\\hline
(0,0) & 1\\\hline
\end{array}
$

So, our joint distribution table would be:

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  Y\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large X}{\phantom{l}} 
    & 0 & 1 & 2 & \text{Sum} \\  \hline
0 & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & 0 & \frac{2}{8} \\  \hline
1 & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{2}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{4}{8} \\  \hline
2 & 0 & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{2}{8} \\  \hline
\text{Sum} & \frac{2}{8} & \frac{4}{8} & \frac{2}{8} & 1 \\  \hline
\end{array}
$

Conditional distribution of $X$,

$P(X=0|Y=0) = \frac{\frac{1}{8}} {\frac{2}{8}} = \frac{1}{2}$
$P(X=1|Y=0) = \frac{\frac{1}{8}} {\frac{4}{8}} = \frac{1}{4}$
$P(X=2|Y=0) = \frac{0} {\frac{2}{8}} = 0$
$P(X=0|Y=1) = \frac{\frac{1}{8}} {\frac{2}{8}} = \frac{1}{2}$
$P(X=1|Y=1) = \frac{\frac{2}{8}} {\frac{4}{8}} = \frac{2}{4}$
$P(X=2|Y=1) = \frac{\frac{1}{8}} {\frac{2}{8}} = \frac{1}{2}$
$P(X=0|Y=2) = \frac{0} {\frac{2}{8}} = 0$
$P(X=1|Y=2) = \frac{\frac{1}{8}} {\frac{4}{8}} = \frac{1}{4}$
$P(X=2|Y=2) = \frac{\frac{1}{8}} {\frac{2}{8}} = \frac{1}{2}$

**Now** for the second part $E[X|Y=l]$ for $l=0,1,2$,

From previous calculation we get:

$E[X|Y=0] = (0 \times \frac{1}{2}) + 
            (1 \times \frac{1}{4}) + 
            (2 \times        0) = 0.25$
$E[X|Y=1] = (0 \times \frac{1}{2}) + 
            (1 \times \frac{2}{4}) + 
            (2 \times \frac{1}{2}) = 1.5$
$E[X|Y=2] = (0 \times 0) + 
            (1 \times \frac{1}{4}) + 
            (2 \times \frac{1}{2}) = 1.25$

**Is this calculation correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You're method is perfect, and I've not seen any arithmetic mistakes!